# crontab not working when sourcing external bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I have crontab which I need it to source global bash in this bash script 
I export Global EVN variables which are used in other scripts 
The problem is that when I invoke the script from crontab script it ignores the 
export Global EVN variables.

Here is the config.sh and its path is: `/home/user/scripts` and I can't move it to other dir.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:$PWD
#Tests path
export MAIN_PATH=/home/user/setup/work
```

And the crontab script

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:$PWD

source $PWD/config.sh

#remove previous crontab
crontab -r
#set crontab
(echo "27 11 * * * $MAIN_PATH/run-from-crontab.sh") | crontab -
#print loaded crontab
sudo crontab -u user -l
```

And in the run-from-crontab.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:$PWD

source $PWD/config.sh

$MAIN_PATH/scripts/test.sh
```

At this point I expect that MAIN_PATH will hold the export MAIN_PATH value 
but I'm getting:

```
/home/user/setup/work/scripts/run-from-crontab.sh: line 3: /home/user/config.sh:
No such file or directory                                                                                             
chmod: cannot access ‘//scripts’: No such file or directory
```

Why is `MAIN_PATH` not passed to the working script?

Comment: Looks like your config.sh didn't get sourced, in your error output, the shell said it didn't find /home/user/config.sh. Try fixing that and it should work.

Comment: unfortunately i can't the config.sh is in other scripts directory and it should be there with all other application directories

Comment: Do you have a way to *know* for sure where config.h would be? If you do, then source it from there, e.g., if it is always in /home/user,  then don't do $PWD/config.sh, change it to /home/user/config.sh. Or, perhaps you're given some part of the path, like "user", then you construct the config file path from that, e.g., `. "/home/$username/config.sh"` or similar.

Comment: i try to make something that is dynamic

Comment: Don't trust $PWD. Instead, refer to ${HOME} which is guaranteed to be set by cron.

Comment: Please try to describe what you are trying to achieve. If needed, edit the question to reflect it. As stated, it is pretty clear why you get an error (cron doesn't have /home/user as the current directory - and never will), how to solve this. Note that the question title and description are a bit misleading - the problem that you have is not with crontab, nor it is with env variables not being set when you source a file. Your script just doesn't get the file from the correct directory. "the config.sh is in some global scripts directory" isn't helpful - I cannot guess where that is.

Comment: @wildplasser i guess $HOME is the best option

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you assume that cron executes your script in a specific directory.The directory where it actually executes may not be the directory that you intended.

In the example above, the script is executed in `/home/user`. As stated by Leo, if the `config.sh` is in that directory, it should work.

Comment: unfortunately i can't and this is the all problem the config.sh is in some global scripts directory

Comment: So, why are you using `$PWD`? It is almost certain that this global scripts directory is not `$PWD`. So instead of using `$PWD`, use the full path-name of the `config.sh`.